# IBM Websphere MQ 7.1.0.2 Tracing

Tags: ibm-mq

I have a number of Queue Managers with a number of Queues. Im using Transmission queues, sender and receiver channels to communicate and transfer messages between the different queue managers.

I have been doing some testing and have found that if you put a wrong queue name in the sender channel just sits there retrying.

Is there a way i can enable tracing or error logging to see that there is an error with the queue name i am trying to send to.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question you posed is yes - there's trace facility (strmqtrc -t detail -t all, recreate, endmqtrc, then look in the mqdata\trace directory at the files noting that on unix you need to dspmqtrc *.TRC first to produce readable FMT files). However, thats almost certainly far *too* much information for what you need.

If you have a channel that wont start, look at the queue manager error logs first (amqerr0*.log in the mqdata\qmgrs\qmgrname\errors), on BOTH sides, and then at the global errors directory (again, both sides).

Generally speaking a sender channel is configured with a transmit queue where it gets the messages off, which obviously needs to exist. I would hope the amqerr0* errors file would give you enough to pin that down. You may also want to play with configuring a dead letter queue to both ends, so if the message cannot be put somewhere it can end up on there, prefixed with a header to say why. If you do this, use MQExplorer to browse the dead letter queue as I believe it expands the header for you (from memory)

Comment: Thanks for the Advice, Had no idea i could find the error codes here. This helped alot. Using this information i found a way of seeing descriptions of the errors and also set up a dead letter queue which in the header of the messages also gives me some very useful information. Thank you for the help Very useful :)